# Посчитать прожади за предыдущий день

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

У меня есть dataframe

```
Товар     Дата         Продано 
a        01.01.2014    100
a        02.01.2014    102
a        03.01.2014    500
a        04.01.2014    305
```

Мне нужно получить следующий DataFrame

```
Товар     Дата       Продано    Продано 1 день назад
a       01.01.2014   100        NaN
a       02.01.2014   102        100
a       03.01.2014   500        102
a       04.01.2014   305        500
```

Comment: Успеха вам в вашем нелегком деле!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [145]: df['Продано 1 день назад'] = df['Продано'].shift()

In [146]: df
Out[146]:
  Товар        Дата  Продано  Продано 1 день назад
0     a  01.01.2014      100                   NaN
1     a  02.01.2014      102                 100.0
2     a  03.01.2014      500                 102.0
3     a  04.01.2014      305                 500.0
```

**UPDATE:** сдвиг в группе:

```
In [42]: df['Продано 1 день назад'] = df.groupby('Товар')['Продано'].shift()

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
  Товар        Дата Продано Продано 1 день назад
0     a  01.01.2014     100                  NaN
1     a  02.01.2014     102                  100
2     a  03.01.2014     500                  102
3     a  04.01.2014     305                  500
4     b  01.01.2014     101                  NaN
5     b  02.01.2014     102                  101
```

Comment: А если я захочу поменять сдвиг (количество дней назад или вперед)?

Comment: @АленаГайбатова, тогда вам наверняка поможет [официальная документация](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) ;)

Comment: не подскажите, как привязать циклический сдвиг к полю Товар (или id)? предположим, если в строчке 4 уже будет товар 'b' тогда в поле Продано 1 день назад уже будет сдвигаться число на 305.

Comment: @АленаГайбатова, т.е. сдвигать группируя по столбцу "Товар"? Можете обновить примеры входных и выходных данных в вопросе или еще лучше задать новый вопрос?